# angular 2 set default scroll to view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In angular 2 mat-select I have 50 items (just integers 1 thru 50). It's current bound value is say 5. 5 is displayed correctly in it's unopened state. If I open the select/drop down to change that value I want the drop down to scroll to item 26 and highlight it so all user needs to do is click. This is because anytime they change that value 99% of the time it is 26. Any pointers on how to do appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your mat select code and how you get the options for it

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer, here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-defualt-option

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer, no data binding in code. If you can show me how to scroll the list and highlight any element in list I am good.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by doing the following.

Set a template reference on `mat-select`

```
<mat-select #matSelect placeholder="List of numbers">
```

Use click event on `mat-form-field` and pass `matSelect` as argument

```
<mat-form-field (click)="focusItem(matSelect)">
```

Set focus to the option index you want

```
focusItem(el){
    el.options['_results'][25].focus()
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuh17s?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: Revised answer to not need `@ViewChild` and to scroll to index `[25]` which is option 26